# Python 3 clips some of my input string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Basically I just take a string input with python (3.4.3):

```
strline = input('Enter clause:\n')
print('\n\n'+strline)
```

But when I tried to process this string, I failed. Then I realized that the first few characters of the string is somehow missing. For example if inputted string is **'to be or not to be'**, *strline* is **'r not to be'**. I tested this by printing *strline* just one line below.

Number of the missing characters are about 20-40 and this number changes every time I run the program again. Length of my string is 536 chars. It contains ':-', parantheses, dots and commas.

I feel that it is a very basic problem, but failed to find it on internet since it is very hard to specify so basic things.

I use Spyder IDE on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: The code looks fine, and executes fine on my command line interpreter. Maybe it's something to do with your IDE? Try executing the same code using the command line interpreter and see if it's any different.

Comment: As other comments pointed out, the code works fine for me too. Try running your code in interactive mode. To enter the interactive mode just run your python executable without giving it a file to run. Then enter your code one line at a time and see what the results are.

Comment: When I ran the commands consequently in IDLE, it worked fine. Now when I restarted my computer, and didn't touch to the code at all, it seems to work fine on Spyder. I thought that I was missing a common practice, but it seems that it was a software quirk.